# Changing SaveFileDialog behaviour with filters

Tags: vb.net, savefiledialog

I have to export, under pressure of a button, some data in different extensions. To do this, I provided a `SaveFileDialog`, but depending on the filter (and so the output file extension), I have to write data with a different process:

- if I have to export it as `.txt` or `.csv`, I have to use writer
- otherwise if I have to export it as `.xlsx`, `.xls` or `.ods` I have to use NPOI

I provided the code both for writer and NPOI and they work singularly. If I try to put them together, `.txt` and `.csv` works, but for `.xlsx`, it exports a corrupted file.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt|CSV Files (*.csv*)|*.csv|Excel 2010 Workbook (*.xlsx*)|*.xlsx|Excel 2000 Workbook (*.xls*)|*.xls|OpenOffice Spreadsheet (*.ods*)|*.ods"
    SaveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = False
    Dim t As Integer
    t = CInt(Form10.Label13.Text)
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt|CSV Files (*.csv*)|*.csv|" Then
                Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
                    For Each o As Object In Form10.ListBox2.Items
                        writer.WriteLine(o)
                    Next
                End Using
            End If
        End If
        If SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel 2010 Workbook (*.xlsx*)|*.xlsx|Excel 2000 Workbook (*.xls*)|*.xls|OpenOffice Spreadsheet (*.ods*)|*.ods|" Then
            Dim fs As New FileStream(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            Dim workbook As IWorkbook = New XSSFWorkbook()
            Dim worksheet As ISheet = workbook.CreateSheet()
            Dim ich As ICreationHelper = workbook.GetCreationHelper()
            Dim rows As New List(Of IRow)
            Dim rowz As IRow = worksheet.CreateRow(0)
            rowz.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(ich.CreateRichTextString("Time [s]"))
            rowz.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(ich.CreateRichTextString("HRR [kW]"))
            For i As Integer = 1 To t
                Dim row As IRow = worksheet.CreateRow(i)
                row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(CDbl(Form10.ListBox1.Items(i)))
                row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(CDbl(Form10.ListBox2.Items(i)))
                rows.Add(row)
            Next i
            workbook.Write(fs)
            fs.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'd like to know if the "if loop" is set properly for filters. Thanks all are gonna answer me. Best regards.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the file path selected by the user and check its extension, e.g.

```vb
Select Case Path.GetExtension(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    Case ".txt", ".csv"
        '...
    Case ".xlsx", ".xls", ".ods"
        '...
End Select
```